# Update existing PowerPoint from data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

My intention is to open an existing PowerPoint presentation along with an existing Excel workbook, and subsequently run a VBA macro from Excel which would update the corresponding values in PowerPoint.

For this I've identified the Shape name of the corresponding text boxes I want to update in PowerPoint by highlighting the specific textbox and used `Format -> Align`. Then I've created 3 columns in Excel with the values:

```
 Slide index   Shape name               Value
 1            Title 2                  =CONCATENATE("REPORT ";YEAR(TODAY()))
 1            Placeholder for date1    =TODAY()
```

I use the macro (which I unfortunately can't remember from which site I copied it):

```
Sub writedata()
Dim c As Object
Dim shapeslide
Dim shapename
Dim shapetext

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.application")
Set pppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

For Each c In Blad2.Range("a2:a" & Blad2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
shapeslide = Blad2.Range("a" & c.Row)
shapename = Blad2.Range("b" & c.Row)
shapetext = Blad2.Range("c" & c.Row).Text
pppres.Slides(shapeslide).Shapes(shapename).TextEffect.Text = shapetext
Next

End Sub
```

My problem is that `Slide 1` wont be updated at all in its corresponding `Shape name`. The only action which happens when I execute this macro is that, for some reason, `Slide 3` has its *font size* modified to become size 35 instead of size 16. I can't understand why that is happening. The Shape name of the shape whose font size is altered is neither written into the Excel workbook, nor is it the same shape name as one of those two written in Excel.

Hopefully someone can shed some light into this.

Comment: May not be your issue, as you may be using shapes and not textboxes. But were you attempting to write data to a text box you'd want to use:

.TextFrame.TextRange = "TEXT TO POPULATE / VARIABLE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets get your slides and shapes listed by excel to ensure that they are what you expect. Sometimes they are really oddly named/IDed. Since you have slides not changing that should and slides changing that should not... we definitely need to doublecheck these. This will itterate through each slide and each shape on that slide and list the slide ID and Name and each shape ID and Name. I have a presentation and the first slide is slide 297 for some reason. Then slide 250 is second. Slide 50 is 3rd. The rest are all numbered oddly also. o.O

Turn on your immediates window to see the debug text.

```
Sub SlidesShapes()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer 

Set ppapp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppres = ppapp.ActivePresentation

For i = 1 To ppres.Slides.Count'slides and shapes start counting at 1 not 0
    Debug.Print ppres.Slides(i).SlideID
    Debug.Print ppres.Slides(i).Name
    For j = 1 To ppres.Slides(i).Shapes.Count
        Debug.Print ppres.Slides(i).Shapes(j).ID
        Debug.Print ppres.Slides(i).Shapes(j).Name
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Also, when you step through your original code (not this snippet) what do you see in your locals window for each step? Anything weird going on there that jumps out at you? Any variables populated with something unexpected or not completely right?